# Is serialVersioUID require in Interfaces(I hope not)?

Tags: java, serialization, serialversionuid

My understanding is `serialVersionUID` is applicable only to classes, because we can create an object only to classes and the concept of serialVersionUID is for object serialization and deserialization.

Comment: By the way, for a class serialVersionUID is not required. If you don't provide one Java will automatically create one for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not required, and more importantly, it will not have any effect on how serialization works in your application.

Since `serialVersionUID` should be static, even if you add it to your interface, it won't be inherited, so you'll need to add one to your implementing class, too. Similarly, if you extend a serializable base class, you need to add `serialVersionUID` again.